# Is there a way to keep references/pointers to objects in unordered_set?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, stl, unordered-set

I have a couple of objects of `class A`. In some other `class B`, I want to keep an unordered_set of objects of `class A`. Note that objects of `class B` thus contain a set which may point to (some of) the same `class A` objects as another set. It is required that these `class A` objects are never copied or anything, as they contain member data that is supposed to be used and changed (shared-in-use) by different objects of `class B` and `class A`.

First, since I come from C, I thought just to use pointers to the object as the values in the set. However, upon coding I saw that I now needed to also pass overridden hash and equality functionality as I have to compare objects of class A for equality on a private member of `class A`. The hashing function thus needs to be a public member function of `class A`.

I was however wondering, since `std::unordered_set::insert()` seems to take a *reference to a value_type*, if it is possible to just use A as the value type for the `std::unordered_set`. This would make the code quite a bit easier, as it would by default use the `== operator` already implemented in `class A`. However, I'm not sure if `std::unordered_set::insert()` copies the objects you pass into it. It seems it doesn't, but the value_type remains A, and not A&.

I also fail to see the difference between `std::unordered_set::insert()` and `std::unordered_set::emplace()`. I don't understand what "copy vs move" means.

TLDR: to keep references to objects of user-defined classes in a set or map, is it possible in this case to use `A*` as value_type? Or `std::reference_wrapper<A>`? Or just the plain `A`?

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
class A {
public:
    bool operator== (A& other);
private:
    B* b;
    size_t id;
    size_t someIntThatMustBeShared;
};

class B {
public:
    std::unordered_set<A ? > as;
};
```

Comment: Both pointers and references have their uses in C++. You need to understand what each one should be used for, and when it should not be used. There is no "one size fits all" answer in C++ for "pointers or references". In fact, every "is it best to do X or Y" in C++ type of a question has the same answer: "yes".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It seems I haven't made my question clear enough. I believe I am sufficiently aware of the difference between pointers and references and I also believe my question shows this. Any feedback on how to improve the clarity of the question is of course greatly appreciated in that regard. I mean to specifically ask about how one would go about using either pointers, references òr objects as valuetypes and which one the better option would be for the usecase described in the question.

Comment: You may be aware of the difference between them, but you are asking this question because you don't know when it's "best" do use one or the other, and that is something that I specifically addressed in my comment. Furthermore, if you attempted to actually use references in an unordered_set, you ...will be unlikely to succeed. At some point, sooner or later, you will realize that you cannot do this, in C++, and the most you can do is use `std::reference_wrapper`. So, before you start musing which is the "better option", looks like you still have some more studying to do, here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you. I have stumbled upon the problem you describe in your comment and have attempted to implement a solution with the `std::reference_wrapper`. You make a good point that this is not clear from the original question, I will edit it. That being said, I'd like to stress that I'm not looking for any general "best" solution, but I believe I've provided a concrete enough usecase to ask for a specific solution _at_  _all_ as I fail to find one that works in any case. Do you advise me to keep trying with the reference_wrapper? Is that the preferred pattern _in this case_?

Comment: Maybe. An intelligent decision as to whether pointers, references, or discrete objects should be used cannot be made based solely on the information given. It depends on many, many other factors. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. For example, based solely on the shown code, the answer would be "don't use pointers or references, just store them in the set". There could be many reasons why the answer will be different as soon as you add one more line to the shown code. This is why nobody on stackoverflow.com can really give you the answer.

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) *It is frequently used as a mechanism to store references inside standard containers.* Sounds like a good options to me.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Does storing the objects directly in the set not cause `A::someIntThatMustBeShared` to be copied upon insertion through `std::unordered_set::insert()`? I assume a modification to that integer on a copied object will not be reflected in all other copies of the object.

Comment: @super Yes I have a version of the program with that implemented. I found however that I had to implement both the hashing functor and equality functor for the `std::unordered_set` anyway, as `std::reference_wrapper<T>` doesn't seem to call the `operator ==` on its `<T>`. So then I was writing the same code I would when using pointers in the first place. So then I asked myself what the point was and if I was overlooking some simple solution to this (i believe not so uncommon) problem, using the actual object as key for example and dynamically allocating all members.

Comment: "Must be shared" is too broad of a description to be useful. "Shared" can mean anything. Your assumption is correct. Still, there are ways to handle this, like `std::shared_ptr` that avoids the direct use of pointers. This is why I wrote: "C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today". Whatever is the "best" approach for the shown code, that's completely, totally, and utterly irrelevant and meaningless. Because as soon as you change one line of the shown code, the "best" approach will likely be different. You must decide that based on your ***entire*** code.

Comment: @AdriaanJacobs The fact that I still don't know if that comparator checks for equality by comparing if they reference the same object, or if the objects have the same value tells me it probably makes sense to not have a default behaviour.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm trying my best but I really don't know how to describe it better. When I wrote _they contain member data that is supposed to be used and changed (shared-in-use) by different objects_ I meant `class A` has an integer that is supposed to be updated on multiple occasions, from a multitude of sources (with this I mean the integer may be accessed through a reference to the object that is contained in a set wherever). Since you've confirmed `std::unordered_set::insert()`copies the argument, how does `std::unordered_set::emplace()`behave differently? Does this offer a solution?

Comment: @super Right now I'm implementing it by keeping raw pointers in the unordered set and then defining a hasher and equalling functor as inner classes of `A` (inner because I need to access private members for their implementation). However I'm struggling with a circular inclusion problem and I can't forward declare the inner classes. I really think there must be a design pattern for this, but I can't seem to get the google search quite right.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've tried using `std::shared_ptr` but I must have misunderstood how they worked because it seemed like I still had to provide my own hasher and "equaller" to use them in a `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok sir I'm sorry if i bothered you. I've only started C++ this week and I do not have any learning material as I'm not taking it as a class, but rather learning it as part of a graduation project I'm involved in. This is the first time I've posted on stackoverflow.com for help and I'm still a bit puzzled what is acceptable to ask and what not.

Comment: Correct. There's very little in c++ that happens automatically, on your behalf. You must do all the work yourself. How many times did I repeat "C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today"? You are beginning to discover why. It takes 3-5 years to reach the "average to proficient" expertise level.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So as I still have to implement those functors myself, why wouldn't I just use a raw pointer as value_type and than also implement them myself? Or a std::reference_wrapper? I want to note here that I did already say this in my first answer to "super".

Comment: There's a big difference between using `std::shared_ptr`, and an ordinary pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: I am the OP and I'm new to C++. My code compiles and runs as expected for now and although I do believe all the below information to be correct, please leave a comment to notify me of any errors.

For those interested, I ended up creating two public functors in class A (inner, as I needed access to private members (using `friend` also would've been an option)) and using them in the declaration of the `std::unordered_set`. For the type i used A*. A better solution might have been a smart pointer but I'm new to all this so I haven't studied those in detail yet.

I learned the following things about `std::unordered_set`:

1. Default equalling and hashing behaviour is only implemented for types listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).
2. If you need anything else, you have 3 options: using some kind of pointer to the type (be that raw, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`, ...), using `std::reference_wrapper<T>`, or using the type itself. Note that references like `A&` are not allowed as value_type for the `std::unordered_set`, hence the wrapper.
3. In the first two options the default implementation (if any) does not 'cascade down' to use any `operator ==` that you may have defined for your type.  In point 5 a solution to this is proposed.
4. In the last option the `operator ==` of your type is used as the default 'equaller'. Only a definition of a hasher is required to work here. You should however be wary that `std::unordered_set::insert()` creates a copy of your inserted element, so if it contains statically allocated member data you should make sure your program still behaves properly when you start copying instances of the type. I think that this is the least verbose solution, and it is also the solution of which I found the most examples. (Using `std::unordered_set::emplace()` might be a solution to the whole copying thing, but I haven't quite figured that out yet.)
5. In general, 'hasher' and 'equalling' functionality can be provided in two ways: through a definition of `std::hash<T>`and/or `std::equal_to<T>`, or through the creation of functors for these purposes. More info on how to do that [here](https://thispointer.com/how-to-use-unordered_set-with-user-defined-classes-tutorial-example/). These essentially do the same thing, so they can be interchanged. As discussed in point 4, there is 1 other option for when you are storing direct types, you can use the `operator ==` as well and then you don't need to specify any 'equaller' upon declaring the `std::unordered_set`.